# Concatenate strings within array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have the array of objects as below. I want to loop through it and get `Closed` property values. It should be a concatenation of all the values found in each object.

For e.g. in below case, i want final result as `121212` since it has 12 in all the 3 objects.

```
const data = [
    {
      "personId": "1208007855",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "1559363884",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "973567318",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    }
  ]
```

can someone let me know how to achieve this. I tried this way but couldnt succeed in achieving the result. I could only get the value of first object. Not sure how i can concatenate and store next values in this loop

There might be a situation where some objects might not have `Closed` property.

```
const totalClosed = data.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    const x = arrayItem.details.Closed;
    console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional way, using `reduce`

```js
const data = [
    {
        "personId": "1208007855",
        "details": {
            "Closed": "12",
            "Analyze": "10"
        }
    },
    {
        "personId": "1559363884",
        "details": {
            "Closed": "12",
            "Analyze": "10"
        }
    },
    {
        "personId": "973567318",
        "details": {
            "Closed": "12",
            "Analyze": "10"
        }
    }
]

const { Closed, Analyze } = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc.Closed += cur?.details?.Closed ?? ''
    acc.Analyze += cur?.details?.Analyze ?? ''
   return acc
}, { Closed: "", Analyze: "" })
console.log({ Closed, Analyze })
```

Comment: @Naren- If i have another property "Analyze" along with "Closed", how can i concatenate values of both these in single reduce ?

Comment: You can use object to saved all strings as a result. let me do that

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.reduce` function:

`data.reduce((accumulator, item) => accumulator += item.details.Closed, '')`

`=> 121212`

Comment: what about the case when  ```data[i].details.Closed ```is ```undefined```

Comment: In the case that a field is undefined, you can write `item.details?.Closed ?? ''` instead of `item.details.Closed`. If `item.details.Closed` is null-ish, it would return an empty string: `data.reduce((accumulator, item) => accumulator += item.details?.Closed ?? '', '')`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
const data = [
    {
      "personId": "1208007855",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "1559363884",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "973567318",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    }
  ];
  result = '';
  for (let i in data) {
      result += data[i].details.Closed
  }
```

Comment: What about the case when ```data[i].details.Closed``` is ```undefined```

Comment: In that case use ```result = '';
  for (let i in data2) {
      if (typeof data2[i]?.details?.Closed != 'undefined') result += data2[i]?.details?.Closed```
  }

Answer (score 2):

If you want a string and have an array, the best method is `reduce`:

```
const totalClosed = data.reduce(function (accumulator, currentVal) {
    const closed = currentVal.details.Closed || '';
    return accumulator + closed;
}, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ***foreach*** exactly the same way you were trying:

```
const data = [
  {
    personId: '1208007855',
    details: {
      Closed: '12'
    }
  },
  {
    personId: '1559363884',
    details: {
      Closed: '12'
    }
  },
  {
    personId: '973567318',
    details: {
      Closed: '12'
    }
  }
];

let totalClosed = '';

data.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
  totalClosed = totalClosed + arrayItem.details.Closed;
});

console.log(totalClosed);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = "";
for(let i=0; i<data.length;i++){
str+= data[i].details.Closed;
}

console.log(str);
```

Also, with forEach, the elements might not be processed in the same order (0 to n) and you may find different results than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement using loops Try Using:

```
const data = [
    {
      "personId": "1208007855",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "1559363884",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "973567318",
      "details": {
        "Closed": "12"
      }
    }
  ];
var res= ''
data.forEach((item)=>{if(item.details.Closed){ res += item.details.Closed;}})
console.log(res)
```

And this can also be done by using higher order functions:
Try using :

```
data.reduce((res, item) =>{if(item.details.Closed)
 res += item.details.Closed;
return res}, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = ''
const totalClosed = data.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
  if(arrayItem.details.Closed){
        str += arrayItem.details.Closed;
  }
});

console.log(str)
```

You can create an empty string and add to it if the closed field exists, if there is another condition in 'Closed' you can check there in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the data entries by destructuring the entry in the reducer and concatenating the `Closed` value to the running `res` (result). You can use the nullish-coalescing operator (`??`) to use an empty string instead of `undefined` when concatenating.

```js
const data = [
  { "personId": "1208007855" , "details": { "Closed": "12" } },
  { "personId": "1559363884" , "details": { "Closed": "12" } },
  { "personId": "0000000000" , "details": { "Open"  : "8"  } }, // New!
  { "personId": "973567318"  , "details": { "Closed": "12" } }
];

const value = data.reduce((res, { details: { Closed } }) => res + (Closed ?? ''), '');

console.log(value);
```